# yii2: Unable to determine the entry script file path - change PHP server environment from cgi to cli

Tags: php, cgi, command-line-interface, yii2, bluehost

I'm using yii2 basic template for my application. I created a console command which executed successfully on my local. But when I run it in terminal on my bluehost site, I got this error "Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Unable to determine the entry script file path.'"

I learn that the issue was about the php environment, that uses cgi instead of cli, got the info here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6244

I confirm it when checking the php -v
host: PHP 5.4.34 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Oct 21 2014 17:19:35)
local(dev): PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25)

How I can change this server environment to use cli instead of cgi.
A step by step guide with bluehost environment would be appreciated.

Comment: solve this issue with the help from this site http://zurmo.org/forums/index.php?/topic/4516-setting-up-bluehost-cron-jobs-on-shared-server/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're trying to run console command with PHP CGI, which have different environment.

You should use PHP CLI, so call php-cli instead of php.

Comment: HUGE help! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Solve my same problem with

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/xyz/yii hello
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is in Shared Hosting providers.

PHP is configured and installed on the server with **two separate executable / binary files** for CLI and CGI (FastCGI).

> PHP CGI (FastCGI) /usr/bin/php
>
> PHP CLI   /usr/local/bin/php

[Read More](https://help.superhosting.bg/en/php-cli.html)

[phpshell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net) or other tools that emulate like this, execute commands in `CGI/FastCGI` mode.

`Cron Jobs` in Shared Hosting are executed under `cli mode`